# video tag only playing audio of local .MOV files AirDropped from iPhone

Tags: javascript, html

My code roughly looks like `<video src={URL.createObjectURL(videoFile)} />` where `videoFile` is a local file from a `file` `input`. I have `.mov` files created from a Quicktime screen recording and the video tag will play the video and audio part of the file, but when I AirDrop a video recording from my iPhone (`.MOV` file) and try to play them, only the audio plays and the video tag is a black screen. There's something about iPhone video recordings that makes the video tag not play the video and only the audio.

Answer (score 0):

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video.mp4"  type="video/mp4">
    <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="video.ogv"  type="video/ogg">
    <source src="video.ogv"  type="video/mov">
</video>
```

here width and height depends on your requirements

Comment: Still getting a black screen

Comment: post your code here, maybe that will be helpful for me what's going on :-)

Comment: Looks like your code except `<source src={require('./IMG_0149.mov')} />` is the only source tag with the required file being a file airdropped from an iPhone